# Dropping articles after the word "of"

Tags: articles

Tell me please why an article is dropped after "of" in the following sentence.

> Studies indicate that many patient and doctors are uncomfortable with the idea of having cost-of-care factor into end-of-life decisions"

The word "factor" is a countable noun, so an article is supposed to be
 there, but it is not.

Comment: *factor* in this case is a verb

Comment: But why is  "the"  dropped before the word "cost" then? Like: having the cost of care factor...

Comment: Because "cost" is an uncountable noun.

Comment: @CanadianYankee - both "cost-of-care" and "end-of-life" look like healthcare jargon to me.  Here in the UK, EOLC is End of Life Care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As StoneyB says, in this particular sentence *factor* (or *factor into*) is the verb

> [**factor**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/factor) (v): to consider or include (something) in making a judgment or calculation, *The company would have made a lot of money, but they neglected to **factor** the rising cost of the raw materials into their business model.*

However, it is possible to rewrite the sentence using factor as a noun:

> Studies indicate that many patient and doctors are uncomfortable with the idea of having **the** cost-of-care **factor** (be) a part of end-of-life decisions"

Here, of course, the article is required.  Plus it's kind of a clumsy sentence. Both mean more or less the same thing, so whether you choose the noun or the verb is a question of style, not substance.

Comment: Is there "to" missing there? Like "They are uncomfortable with the idea of having to factor the cost of care into end of life decisions." does that make sense?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope  That would be fine, but it would change "factor" back to the verb.  "Cost-of-care factor" is a compound noun.

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope This *having* is not the quasi-modal *have to* but "experiential" *have*, which takes a bare infinitival clause as its complement. For instance, "I had (=*experienced*) lightning strike my house". (And the passive version of the complement clause omits the infinitive auxiliary *be*: "I had my house struck by lightning.")